# Golangでsha256のバイト同士を連結してハッシュ化したい。

Tags: go

Golangで3つの[32]byte型の変数

```
a := sha256.Sum256("aaaa")
b := sha256.Sum256("bbbb")
c := sha256.Sum256("cccc")
```

を連結して更にsha256を計算したいです。
要するに`d := sha256.Sum256(a+b+c)`にようなことをしたいです。
普通に`bytes.Join`を使ってみましたが、[]byteと[32]byteは型が違うのでできないとエラーが出てしまいました。

どのように連結したハッシュ値を求めればいいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a, b, cの連結は`append(append(a[:], b[:]...), c[:]...)`で可能ですが、連結したハッシュを求めたい場合は`Write`を使ったほうが事前に連結する必要がないので便利です。

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := sha256.Sum256([]byte("aaaa"))
    b := sha256.Sum256([]byte("bbbb"))
    c := sha256.Sum256([]byte("cccc"))

    hash := sha256.New()
    hash.Write(a[:])
    hash.Write(b[:])
    hash.Write(c[:])

    d := hash.Sum(nil)
    fmt.Println(d)
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます!!できました!!

Answer (score 2):

それでは別解を。個々のメッセージダイジェストを文字列(hex string)に変換して結合、`[]byte` 型に戻して全体のメッセージダイジェストを求めています。

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    a := fmt.Sprintf("%x", sha256.Sum256([]byte("aaaa")))
    b := fmt.Sprintf("%x", sha256.Sum256([]byte("bbbb")))
    c := fmt.Sprintf("%x", sha256.Sum256([]byte("cccc")))

    h, _ := hex.DecodeString(a + b + c)
    sum := sha256.Sum256(h)

    fmt.Printf("sum = %v\nsum(hex) = %s\n", sum, fmt.Sprintf("%x", sum))
}
```